# Find out Active Ajax Request in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, abort

I used `abort()` to cancel / abort an Ajax request, but now I want to cancel only active ajax requests. How could I do it?

Comment: in my case we are using not a local variable to store ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin such as http://plugins.jquery.com/ajaxQueue/

Also, You are best off to also incorporate a delay before sending the response so that you don't needlessly overload your server with requests. Instead of using time differences or arrays I would just keep a reference to the last ajax request created. You would abort that request each time a new one is made.